# Angular - create a big and dynamic table

Tags: angular, web-applications, websocket

i need to create a big and dynamic table in Angular. the data coming from web server via a websocket and save in a Map.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit()
{
this.socket=io("localhost");
this.socket.on('data' , (t)=>{

// parse data 
let data = JSON.parse(t);
//check if data is already exist in Map
let item = this.datas.get(data.Id.toString());
if(item){
// if exist update it
}
else{
// if not exist add it to map
}

});
}
}
```

i create a table to show data like this:

```
<div >
   <tr *ngFor="let data of datas ;  let i = index">

  <td>{{ data.info1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ data.info2 }}</td>
  <td>{{ data.info3 }}</td>
  <td>{{ data.info4 }}</td>

  </tr>

</div>
```

it is possible to get hundreds of json data unit received from webserver per second and the size of the Map that i sotre data in it grow up to thousands of items;

i have 2 problem :

1- with this code the table is so big and the page has a horrible lag. what is the best solution to show a big table with thousands of row and with data that change frequently ? and also i looking for a solution to load table partialy and dynamically if possible.

2- i get error for code i write and it doesn't work.

"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Virtualize the table rows. Check out ag grid to see how that's done.
2) Try moving the setting of local data to after view init (`ngAfterViewInit`), but this really should be done in a service. Post the full stack.

If you are using socket.io, the payload should already be JSON, no need for JSON.parse.